# Can't capture first onkeypress event in JavaScript/jQuery when contenteditable=true

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Here is the code:

```
<div onclick="this.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');"
    onkeypress="console.info(event.keyCode)">foo</div>
```

This is how I expected to work: user clicks a `div`, it is editable, then I may intercept some key events to run customized handling with Enter, Tab, Arrow keys.

The problem is, you **can** edit the `div` after click, but you **can not** get the first key press event from `onkeypress`. You can only get a keypress event if you press **twice**.

I am using Chrome Dev v12 on Win7 32 bit. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `this.focus` like this:

```
<div onclick="this.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');this.focus();"
onkeypress="console.info(event.keyCode)">foo</div>
```

I have tried here http://jsfiddle.net/carlesandres/At9uK/ and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this (jquery way):

```
<div id="div1"> foo </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#div1").click(function(){
      $(this).attr("contenteditable", true);
   }).keypress(function(event){
      console.info(event.keyCode);
   });
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Ha, this is exactly why I am asking. It won't work (at least on Chrome)